# OPOS PosExplorer.GetDevice() returns null in .net 4.5 environment?

Tags: c#, .net, epson, opos, pos-for-.net

[OPOS PosExplorer.GetDevice() returns null when executed in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481436/opos-posexplorer-getdevice-returns-null-when-executed-in-windows-service)

the source above seems to have so few response, so i was hoping there could be an elaborate explanation/link that can help us on how to implement the security for opos setup?

We are using the same device Epson TM-U220B.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a reasonably old post but i'll add a bit of information for starters. If you're still searching for an active solution I can try and shed some more light om the topic.

Have you installed the OPOS Common Control Objects (CCOs)? I recommend checking out Curtiss Monroe's website (http://monroecs.com/oposccos_current.htm).

Once installed, register the ActiveX COM-Objects you desire with regsvr32 and try running your application again.

Let me know how it goes. A.

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of search and ask Microsoft forums, they provide a patch for this problem.

Download this patch from Microsoft and solve this!

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34799

I use the EPSON TM-T20II and .NET 4.5 Framework and it Works!

Let me know if this solved your problem.

Regards!

Comment: after patching it gives me error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.